# Killing sudo-started subprocess in python

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, sudo, kill

I am running with a user that can make root-level calls without having to supply a password. My user currently does something like this

```
pr = subprocess.Popen("sudo sleep 100".split())
sleep(5)
pr.kill()
```

but that leads to this error because the user isn't root so it can't kill a root process

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1572, in kill
    self.send_signal(signal.SIGKILL)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1562, in send_signal
    os.kill(self.pid, sig)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

so I try to do something like this

```
pr = subprocess.Popen("sudo sleep 100".split())
sleep(5)
kill_pr = subprocess.Popen("sudo kill {}".format(pr.pid))
```

but that doesn't kill the process in question. For example, if

```
>> subprocess.Popen("sudo sleep 100".split()).pid
5000
```

but

```
$ pgrep sleep
5001
```

so it seems that the `pid` returned from `subprocess.Popen("..").pid` is one higher than the actual pid of the process running the command that I want to kill

I'm assuming that the `pid` returned from the `Popen` call is the parent process, so I try doing something like

`sudo kill -- -$PID`, where `$PID` is the one returned from `Popen`, but that just gives me

```
kill: sending signal to -2100 failed: No such process
```

why doesn't the process exist?

Essentially, I just need a way to run a command with `sudo` using python's subprocess, then be able to kill it when I need to. I'm assuming I need to run some type of `sudo kill` command with the `pid` of the process I'm trying to kill or something like that but I'm unable to determine exactly how to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I figured it out, the issue was that if I did this

```
import subprocess, os
pr = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "sleep", "100"])
print("Process spawned with PID: %s" % pr.pid)
pgid = os.getpgid(pr.pid)
subprocess.check_output("sudo kill {}".format(pgid))
```

it would kill the process that started the python interpreter

```
>>> Terminated
```

so instead, I set the `preexec_fn` to `os.setpgrp`

```
import subprocess, os
pr = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "sleep", "100"], preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)
print("Process spawned with PID: %s" % pr.pid)
pgid = os.getpgid(pr.pid)
subprocess.check_output("sudo kill {}".format(pgid))
```

in another shell, if I check

```
pgrep sleep
```

nothing shows up, so it is actually killed.

Answer (score 3):

When you execute `pgrep sleep` you are shown the PID of the `sleep` command, running as a child of the `sudo` process you created.

As a quick demo, I saved the following as `subproc.py`:

```
import subprocess
pr = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "sleep", "100"])
print("Process spawned with PID: %s" % pr.pid)
```

When running this script, we can see two processes spawned:

```
~/$ python subproc.py
Process spawned with PID: 5296

~/$ ps all | grep sleep
    0  5296     1     sudo sleep 100
    0  5297  5296     sleep 100
```

You'll notice that the PID you know about in your code is the 'parent' sudo process. This is the process you should kill, but you'll need to use sudo to do it:

```
subprocess.check_call(["sudo", "kill", str(pr.pid)])
#You might want to wait for the process to end:
os.waitpid(pr.pid, 0)
```

Comment: the issue is that I can't call `pr.kill()` because `pr` was started with root privileges and my python process is not. When I try to run `pr.kill()` I get the stack trace shown in the original post. This is why I was trying the fancy stuff with `sudo kill` and what not

Comment: `
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> pr = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "sleep", "100"])
>>> print("Process spawned with PID: %s" % pr.pid)
Process spawned with PID: 8057
>>> pr.kill()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1572, in kill
    self.send_signal(signal.SIGKILL)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1562, in send_signal
    os.kill(self.pid, sig)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted`

Comment: how could it kill the sudo process without root privileges? My `python` process isn't started as root, the "sudo sleep 100" command runs okay because I have sudo-without-password privileges for my user, but the pr.kill() still fails because I'm not root -- I'm running Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @JohnAllard Python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: hmm, that makes sense but I can't get it to work. running python 2.7

Comment: that unfortunately does not work - If I run the code that you run I get something like `Process spawned with PID: 25861`,  but if I then, in another shell on the same computer, do `pgrep sleep`, I see `25862`, and the `os.waitpid` call never ends.

Comment: If you use `pgrep sudo` what PID do you see in the other shell?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with root subprocess but the answers here and here- [Python how to kill root subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51240992/python-how-to-kill-root-subprocess) did not worked for me.

At the end the only thing that worked was:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", exe_path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
.
.
.
os.system("sudo pkill -9 -P " + str(proc.pid))
```

Without the need for- preexec_fn=os.setpgrp

Comment: It worked! Thank you. Are you sure about `-9`? Didn't find anything about it in the man page and it's working without it too.

Comment: @bernardolansing, [pkill will send the specified signal, by default SIGTERM](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill), 9 is `SIGKILL`. it will work without `-9` because the default `SIGTERM` also killed your process.