# How to kill a python subprocess started as sudo? Previous SO answers leave zombies

Tags: python, macos, subprocess, sudo

**Objective:**

1. On MacOS, I want to run the `powermetrics` utility from a python script in the background.
2. The python script will continue to execute some other work while the `powermetrics` utility logs the power statistics in the background.
3. When the work is done, I want to stop the `powermetrics` utility running in the background.

**Problem**

1. `powermetrics` requires sudo privileges to run.
2. I've looked at previous Stack Overflow answers and haven't found a way to kill sudo process without leaving zombies i.e. the `powermetrics` continues to run and add to the output file (specified with -u parameter). Other SO posts

   - [Killing sudo-started subprocess in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50618411/killing-sudo-started-subprocess-in-python)
   - [Python how to kill root subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51240992/python-how-to-kill-root-subprocess)

**Code:**

Here's my current test code

```
cmd = "sudo powermetrics -i 1000 --samplers cpu_power,gpu_power -a -n 20 --hide-cpu-duty-cycle --show-usage-summary --show-extra-power-info -u " + outputFile
pr = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
print("Process spawned with PID: %s" % pr.pid)
pgid = os.getpgid(pr.pid)
print("Process spawned with Group ID: %s" % pgid)

time.sleep(5)

os.system("sudo pkill -9 -P " + str(pgid))
```

Comment: Terminology note: If it is still running, then it is not a zombie. A zombie process is a process that has terminated, but is still in the process table because its parent has not collected the exit status yet.

Comment: Noted, thank you for the clarification 

Comment: I just added a detailed and tested answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69630062/subprocces-popen-kill-process-started-with-sudo/75829227

Answer (score 0):

I see several issues:

1. A zombie process is just an entry in the process table (no memory, no CPU), but you wrote it continues to run.
2. The unconditional KILL `-9` signal is used for "runaway" processes, i.e. when regular ways to stop failed. Read the docs for the process you want to stop. If unsure, use the default SIGTERM first, wait few seconds for a cleanup and only if the process did not stop, kill it with SIGKILL.
3. The `-P` option is documented as *"Only match processes whose parent process ID is listed"*, but your process is using the *group* ID, not the *process* ID. Did you mean `-G` instead?

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out by using the following 


```os.system("sudo pkill -u root powermetrics")```

Comment: @devcoder I'd like to suggest to specify the process to be stopped directly by its ID with `sudo kill -TERM <PID>"`