# Sending a Ctrl+C SIGINT to sudoed C subprocess from python framework

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, sigint

I'm running a python subprocess using:

```
p = Popen(["sudo", "./a.out"])
```

where `a.out` is a C executable which runs continuously until a SIGINT or Ctrl+C signal is sent to it. I've had trouble with `subprocess.Popen` object functions such as `send_signal()` because `Operation not permitted` errors are raised due to the `sudo` nature of the executable. After this I tried to send a SIGINT to the subprocess via:

```
os.system(f"sudo kill -2 {p.pid}")
```

but this doesn't seem to target the process correctly. Running a quick `sudo netstat -lpnt` check shows the `a.out` process is still running on a pid which is different to the one which `p.pid` returned (usually by a few integers, i.e. `p.pid` returns 3031 but `a.out` is 3035). Anything that I've misunderstood?

Comment: does your executable spawns child processes? then maybe try using $ pkill -P <pid> as per https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124127/kill-all-descendant-processes

Comment: Yes this worked! `os.system(f"sudo kill -2 -P {p.pid})" ` did the trick, thanks!

Comment: posted this as an answer so that people could see solution easily, but then found that it's duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50618411/killing-sudo-started-subprocess-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually getting *pid* of and killing sudo process (that forked your application process). Instead you should kill the whole process group with:

```
import subprocess, os
p = Popen(["sudo", "./a.out"])
pgid = os.getpgid(p.pid)
subprocess.check_output("sudo kill {}".format(pgid))
```

or with the help of **pkill**:

```
import subprocess
p = Popen(["sudo", "./a.out"])
subprocess.call(f"sudo pkill -2 -P {p.pid})
```